# Would a city get the bonuses from an adjacent natural wonder?

Tags: civilization-6

I am looking at the Cliffs Of Dover. If I were to drop a settlement on one of the tiles of it, would the city have the usual 2 food, 1 production -- and the two gold and the three culture? That'd be *sweet*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot build cities, wonders, or districts on top of [natural wonders](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Natural_Wonder_(Civ6)). Their bonuses are either flat bonuses or tile based bonuses where they boost at least 1-4 spaces around them.

The [Cliffs of Dover](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Cliffs_of_Dover_(Civ6)) are no exception and

> "**cannot be developed or improved**. Because of this, the Cliffs may be
>   more of a hindrance than an asset later in the game"

Comment: Ah! Most wonders are impassable but this is passable so I was wondering.